# Apache 2.4 showing Symfony 1.4 index.php as plain text

Tags: php, apache, symfony

this is my first post in StackOverFlow, my question is pretty simple, I was doing the Jobeet project using Symfony 1.4 (https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Propel), I configured my VirtualHosts and everything and when I try to display my index, it shows up as plain text

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
    sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

I tried adding these lines at the end too

```
    # PHP 7 specific configuration
    LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

(The file exists)

> But I get a **500 Internal Server Error** when doing so.

I just wanna know what am I doing wrong? Since I'm new to Apache and Symfony.

PS: I'm using Apache 2.4 and got the latest php 7.3.3.

Comment: Hey, can you show the vhost config please?

Comment: When you get a 500, check your apache error logs. On windows they may be found under: ```C:\Apache\logs\```. I am not quite sure about the path, so search for an error.log.
Symfony 1.4 is quite old and I am pretty sure, it is not compatible with PHP 7.3. Why not using the current symfony version? May be that is a better starting point: https://jobeet-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: I'm in my 3rd year of college and got an internship with a company that uses Symfony 1.4, that's why and yeah the problem was the PHP version, downgraded to php 5.6.40 and everything works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone having the same problem as me, it turned out Symfony 1.4 doesn't support PHP 7.3 so I downgraded to 5.6.40 and it worked